# Changing variables in Classes doesn't work | Python

Tags: python, oop

I have written this code in python. My main goal is to change the value of the variable 'a' by the value of the variable 'b' and then return\print that modified 'a' value but it is returning '0' it is not changing the value of 'a'.

```
class ClassA:
    a = 0
    def func(self):
        b = 32
        ClassA.a = b
    
    print(a)

con = ClassA()
con.func()
```

Output:

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

your print statement is executed at the time the class is defined... long before you instantiate it and call the method. move the output elsewhere and you'll see the result of your change.

Answer (score 0):

to acsess the a variable from ClassA object you should declare a as "self.a" like the code below, also the "print(a)"statementshould be inside the function func

```py
class ClassA:
    a = 0
    def func(self):##you should reindent "print(a)" and declare a by using self.a
        b = 32
        self.a = b
        print(a)

con = ClassA()
con.func()

print(con.a)
```